# Recommended server to run an application built with Polymer

Tags: polymer

`Polyserve` is what I've been using until now while developing my web application based on Polymer framework. Now, that I have an Amazon Linux server up and running, I've to deploy my web app for production. 
Since `polyserve` is not recommended for production environments, which one should I go for? How about Apache+PHP

Answer (score 1):

"Apache+PHP" implies a PHP service to me, but if you've been using `polyserve` all this time, I assume you don't actually require a backend at all, and you're just serving static files.

If that's the case, I recommend deploying to [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/), which has a free tier.

If you otherwise prefer to stay with the Amazon Linux server, Apache is fine, but I recommend [NGINX](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/).

Answer (score 1):

As Tony said, any static web server should do. One thing you may need though is some support for Single Page Apps.

I use [local-web-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/local-web-server) on my dev box and also to run on Heroku. Here's my [Procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile):

```
web: ws -s index.html $PORT
```

That said, you can even host a Polymer app using GitHub pages. To do that you can use this simple trick called [rafrex/spa-github-pages](https://github.com/rafrex/spa-github-pages#user-content-usage-instructions). See how I used it to host a demo of my elements on GitHub: http://t-code.pl/ld-navigation

Comment: Ok! However, there is a slight concern.With `polyserve` the `polymer.json` file in my project's root directory which has a key called `entrypoint` apparently allows me to customize my `URL`. For example, if I type `entrypoint: "myentrypoint"`, then my web app is loaded when I hit `localhost:port/myentrypoint`. The same does not happen in case of other servers right now. This is what I need to figure out. It's just static for other servers. Ex. firing `localhost:port/projectdirectoryname` loads `localhost:port/projectdirectoryname/index.html` but `localhost:port/myentrypoint` does not work

Answer (score 1):

If you're familiar with Node.js you can serve your Polymer elements using express framework. I used this script to serve polymer starter-kit appication on Heroku:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

// serve your elements
app.use('/src', express.static('src'));
// serve bower_components
app.use('/bower_components', express.static('bower_components'));
// serve index.html
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile('views/index.html');
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, function () {
  console.log(`App listening on port ${port}!`);
});
```